# Reading a Recipe to control data processing steps

Tags: c#

I have a text file in the general format:

```
ThreadID, MethodName, [Param1 | Param2 | ... ]
```

And I have a Utility class that looks like:

```cs
public static class Util
{
    public static List<double> Foo(List<double> Source, double Scale)
    {
        List<double> l = new List<double>(Source);
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
        {
            l[i] = l[i] * Scale;
        }
        return l;
    }

    public static void Fud(List<double> Source, string Name)
    {
        //... Chart Series
    }
    public static bool Fee(CustomClass MyClass, double Limit1, int Limit2)
    {
        //... Test MyClass values against input limits
        return true; // false;
    }
}
```

So I was using a switch/case which given the method name from the text file, would then parse and pass along arguments to the method in the case.  The sudo code was something to the effect of:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> TextFile;
        List<double>[] Register = new List<double>[3];   //lists containing data that is moved, mutated and converted to CustomClass
        CustomClass MyClass = new CustomClass();
        bool Passed = false;

        foreach (var line in TextFile)
        {
            string methodName = Util.ParseMethod(line);          //parsed from file
            string param1, param2, param3, param4 = Util.ParseParams(line);          //parsed from file
            switch (methodName)
            {
                case "Foo":
                    Register[param1] = Util.Foo(Register[param2], param3);
                    break;

                case "Fud":
                    Util.Fud(Register[param1], param3);
                    break;

                case "Fee":
                    Passed = Util.Foo(MyClass, param1, param2);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I disliked having the logic split up and every time I develop a new utility method, I have to manually add another case statement.  The case statement became difficult to maintain because design time errors (typos in strings/updates) usually only got caught during run-time.

I tried to convert this all to a Factory architecture, but I can't seem to accommodate for the different method definitions.  I was hoping to do away with the Utility class and define each method in it's own class using a factory interface.

```cs
public interface IRecipe
{
    string GetFactoryKey();
    string SerializeArgs(object[] args);
    object[] DeserializeArgs(string args);
    ??? DoWork(???);
}
```

The problem is because of how different each method in the utility class was, I can't find a way to define it in the Interface properly.  The end result I want is that I can replace the switch in the foreach loop with generic code and that all the nitty gritty logic, parsing, method definitions, error checking and validation is defined in each class implementing the factory interface and not the method caller.  I've run out of things to google for as I don't know what I want to do is even called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out... this is my complete proof of concept so far.  Still a bit ugly, but I at least have the ugliness encapsulated in each factory class. Which means the caller in Main can stay quite generic for easy use in a loop.  I'll refactor this a bit more still as I do the real implementation.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<double>[] Reg = new List<double>[2]; for (int i = 0; i < Reg.Length; i++) { Reg[i] = new List<double>(); }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            { Reg[1].Add(1.0); }            //Dummy data

            var obj = ClassFactory.CreateStep("AmplifySignal");
            object[] Args = obj.DeserializeProperties(" ");
            Args[0] = Reg;
            dynamic result = obj.Run(Args);

            if (result != null)
            { Thread.Sleep(0); }    //breakpoint

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    internal static class ClassFactory
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<String, Type> _recipe_instructions;

        static ClassFactory() { _recipe_instructions = MapIFactory(); }

        private static IDictionary<string, Type> MapIFactory()
        {
            // Get the assembly that contains this code
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            // Get a list of all the types in the assembly
            Type[] allTypes = asm.GetTypes();

            var d = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
            foreach (var type in allTypes)
            {
                if (type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && type.GetInterface(typeof(IFactory).ToString()) != null)
                {
                    // Create a temporary instance of that class...
                    object inst = asm.CreateInstance(type.FullName, true, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null, null);
                    if (inst != null)
                    {
                        // And generate the product classes key
                        IFactory mapKey = (IFactory)inst;
                        object key = mapKey.GetFactoryKey();
                        inst = null;

                        //Add the results to a Dictionary with the Name as a key and the Type as the value
                        d.Add((string)key, type);
                    }
                }
            }
            return d;
        }

        internal static IFactory CreateStep(String key)
        {
            Type type;
            if (_recipe_instructions.TryGetValue(key, out type))
            { return (IFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(type); }
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Unable to locate key: {0}", key));
        }
    }

    public interface IFactory
    {
        string GetFactoryKey();
        string SerializeProperties();
        object[] DeserializeProperties(string args);
        dynamic Run(params object[] args);
    }

    public class AmplifySignal : IFactory
    {
        public string GetFactoryKey()
        { return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name; }
        public object[] DeserializeProperties(string args)
        { return new object[] { null, (int)1, (double)2.1 }; }
        public string SerializeProperties()
        { return " 1 | 2.1 "; }

        public dynamic Run(params object[] args)
        {
            // Build Inputs
            List<double>[] registers = (List<double>[])args[0];
            List<double> waveform = (List<double>)registers[(int)args[1]];
            double factor = (double)args[2];

            // Do Work
            double[] Result = waveform.ToArray();      //Localize and Deep Copy
            for (int i = 0; i < Result.Length; i++)
            { Result[i] *= factor; }
            List<double> result = Result.ToList();    //breakpoint

            // Write Result
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If I have done something truly sacrilegious here, and there's a better way to accomplish the same thing then by all means I'm open to suggestions.  I'll wait a day or two before accepting this as the answer to allow for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

What if the DoWork method took a single string argument (the comma-delimeted parameters) and split it up as appropriate?  Then you could still use a simple interface and leave the details to each Recipe.

Another option would be a string array as the parameter, similar to how you spin off work into new threads (specifying a method to call and an array containing its parameters.)

Comment: Yes, I started to go in that direction, but because I want to pass in Lists<T> based off an Index and not just the index value itself to some methods, I need the flexibility of passing an object array.  You did get me thinking though that I could pass complex objects in via class properties and pass parameters in via a string.  Could I then maybe do 'T DoWork<T>(string params)' and when I call it using the factory '(foo)object = Factory.Step<foo>(key);'  if that could work then can foo in the above bit also be made generic maybe using reflection?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you occasionally return something from the DoWork method?  It seems like any error handling would be addressed within the DoWork method itself.  Then you could pass in List<object> and let each recipe cast the items in the list as necessary.

Comment: Yes, I definitely need things passed in and out of the DoWork() method.  I posted my proof of concept, which compiles and works, but feel free to offer any more feedback :)