# Can a DynamicMethod access variables outside of it?

Tags: c#, .net

Can a Dynamic Method work like a normal method or code, in that it can access variables where variables can normally be accessed, call methods, and initialize variables (of course in the scope of the method)?

The only examples I've seen is where it is passed some parameters and returns some value and does nothing to change any variables outside of it.

I'm talking about the System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod class. I'm having trouble understanding it since one needs to use MSIL which I don't know much of yet.

Comment: I am not familiar with the exact function you're talking about (Emit.DynMeth), however the end result you want is certainly possible.  I am working on something similar right now, though I went about it differently.  Let me know if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146006/reading-a-recipe-to-control-data-processing-steps

Comment: About DynamicMethod: "Defines and represents a dynamic method that can be compiled, executed, and discarded." - I want to use this for automatic generation of code to be run inside the larger application. I'm trying to do this instead of going the two app domains route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  A DynamicMethod can be attached to a class, in which case it can access class-private static fields (and possibly class-private fields if the DynamicMethod is an instance method, but I don't recall whether that's a supported scenario).  It can also access assembly-internal methods, properties, and types that are internal to the assembly in which the DynamicMethod is created.

What's the scenario you're using dynamic methods for?

I have some blog articles about dynamic programming, including a couple entries about using the DynamicMethod class on my blog: http://robpaveza.net/tag/dynamic-programming .  Specifically, [this article](http://robpaveza.net/improving-performance-with-dynamic-methods-part-1-the-problem-definition) talks about how to calculate a file revision proof, and you can see the result implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/jinxbot/source/browse/trunk/development/projects/BNSharp/MBNCSUtil/Util/CheckRevisionCompiler.cs) (evidently, I never wrote part 2, but the implementation in BN# that I linked was the result of the analysis).

Let me walk you through the Compile method:

1. Type parameterType = typeof(uint).MakeByRefType()

The final method is going to take out uint parameters; this line obtains a reference to the uint-ref runtime type.  The method declaration would look like this if I were to write it in normal C#:

```
public static void CheckRevision(out uint a, out uint b, out uint c, out uint s);
```

38-40. foreach (string formula in formulas) CompileStandardFormula(generator, formula)

As I mention in my blog post about it, the math that I do is always provided in the form of:

```
A=A-S B=B-C C=C+A A=A+B
```

Where A, B, and C are state variables and S is an input (the next uint value from the file).

The CompileStandardFormula function emits the IL that computes the logic for one individual operation of the four shown.  Recall that the CLR is a stack-based state machine, and math operations occur with the values on the stack being popped and results being pushed.  So, for A=A-S, for example, the following IL is what would be emitted:

```
ldarg.0  // push &A, which is a reference to the location that actually contains the value of A
ldarg.0  // push &A
ldind.u4 // dereference the top-most value on the stack, which puts the actual value of &A ready for operation
ldarg.3  // push &S
ldind.u4 // dereference &S
sub      // subtracts [stack-1] from [stack-2], which effectively is A-S
stind.u4 // remember the first ldarg.0? That's getting accessed now and the subtraction result is going there
```

So, at this point, it should be pretty easy to figure out: my DynamicMethod compiles the math operation required to update all state variables for a single pass in the file.  After all of the IL is emitted, because we know the state of the stack has nothing on it (more than when the method entered, anyway), we can just throw out a quick 'ret' instruction and we're done.

Anyway, hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well its only an application for myself, but I'm trying to apply user-defined formulas/math to lots of data as fast as possible and collecting the aggregate results. Right now I have an application read my formulas, and input them into a visual studio solution and compile and run it. It would be great if instead  the formulas could be put into a running application that does not need to be compiled again and again. But I still want the formulas to be compiled, not interpreted. So that's what I'm trying to do in the simplest form.

Comment: DynamicMethod is a good approach for what you're doing.  The IL is the hardest part to grok, but judicious use of writing the C# code by hand, compiling it, and looking at it in ILDASM will take you a long way!

Comment: Thanks for the answer again but I may be going slightly off topic here but I just noticed this thing: http://codeinject.codeplex.com/ - and I have no clue what it is yet it seems it may be something helpful for me. Do you know what it is? Thanks.